# Wordpress 404 in nginx logs after changing permalinks

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx

So I have my landing page setup in **/usr/share/nginx/html** and blog in **/usr/share/nginx/blog**

As you can see in the config below, the blog is configured as an alias. Whenever someone tries to reach the blog eg: **you.com/blog** it takes them to **you.com/blog/**. Still not a big deal to worry about. So in wordpress, the urls are setup to plain. Everything works till this point without any issues. Now, due to asthetics, the urls need to look better, ie: post-name. Eg: **you.com/blog/name-of-my-post**. If the config is changed in wordpress from plain to post-name nginx gives a 404 with the following message

```
2017/05/03 09:28:00 [error] 2869#0: *1492652 "/usr/share/nginx/blog/my-post/index.html" is not found (2: No such file or directory), client: 73.1.2.24, server: you.com, request: "GET /blog/my-post/ HTTP/1.1", host: "you.com", referrer: "https://you.com/blog/"
```

I'm noticing index.html is getting attached at the end. After trying out different changes in the php/blog block I'm still stuck on 404. Here's the config we're running.

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 ;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_certificate /var/keys/api_ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/keys/api_priv.key;
    server_name you.com;

    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ uri.html = 404;
        }   

    location /blog {
        alias /usr/share/nginx/blog;
        if (!-e $request_filename) {
           rewrite /blog/wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;
           rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) $2 last;
           rewrite ^(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php) $2 last;
        }   
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
        location ~ \.php {
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            $document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
        }
    }
}
```

How can I get the **/blog/my-post-here** instead of the plain type **you.com/blog/?p=10**

Notes: Blog (**/usr/share/nginx/blog**) & Website (**/usr/share/nginx/html** plain HTML) are in 2 separate folders. You should not be able to do any php outside the **/blog** block.

**Edit 2017-May-04**

Modified nginx.config successfully redirecting to **blog/post-name**

```
server {
    root /usr/share/nginx/html;
    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 ;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_certificate /var/keys/api_ssl.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /var/keys/api_priv.key;
    server_name xyz.com;

    index index.html index.php index.htm;

    location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ uri.html = 404;
    }   


    location /blog {
    alias /usr/share/nginx/blog;
    index index.html index.php;
    try_files $uri $uri/ @blog;
    expires 30d;
    if ($uri ~ "^/index.php") {
        rewrite /  redirect;
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
    }
}

location @blog {
    rewrite ^/blog/(.*) /blog/index.php?$args;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your nginx configuration seems wrong.
1) take outside your block from the blog
`location ~ \.php {fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;include fastcgi_params;fastcgi_index index.php;$document_root/$fastcgi_script_name;
}`
And replace your block with below code.
`location /blog {index index.html index.php;try_files $uri $uri/ @blog;expires 30d;if ($uri ~ "^/index.php"){rewrite /  redirect;}}location @blog {rewrite ^/blog/(.*) /blog/index.php?$args;
}`
it will help

Comment: sitll if you get error of css and js or images like static content.
location ~* \.(?:ico|js|css|gif|jpe?g|png|gz|svg|svgz|ttf|otf|woff|eot|mp4|ogg|ogv|webm|tsv)$ {
  root YOUR ROOT DIRECTORY;
      expires 365d;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*";
  add_header Pragma public;
  add_header Cache-Control "public";
 }

Comment: Hey Ankit, I kept php inside the /blog block as I don't want non /blog URLs using any php scripts. Everything is working as expected & updated the nginx config file above & Marked your solution as the Answer. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

If you saved your permalinks so it shows the post title in the url should the following code:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri.html $uri/ uri.html = 404;
 }
```

Not look like this:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
}
```

You do not need to set the /blog manually, wordpress will do this for you if you have the above in your nginx configuration. I can upload my entire configuration if you like.

Comment: location / has the same thing you posted, location /blog has the second one. It would be great if you could post your nginx config if you're running the same type on environment (blog is sitting in a seperate folder than html)

Comment: The nginx/html folder is your non-wordpress website? and nginx/blog is the root of your wordpress installation?

Comment: Correct. wordpress uses php while the website (landing-page) doesn't use php it's plain html.

Answer (score -1):

Seems that your site have definite **permission** or **rewrite module** issues, so it cant not rewrite .**htaccess** file. Please check with your Hosting Provider and ask to rewrite module on for **Apache** or the **server** they are using. And also ask to give write permission to root folder so wordpress can create .**htaccess** file while you change the **permalink**.

Hope it helps.

Comment: He is using nginx, not apache.

Comment: So I mentioned it in my answer, hope that he/she can see that. Please read it carefully before you mark negative to anybody.

Comment: I read your "solution" just fine. You are saying he should change from nginx to apache. That is not a solution.

Comment: I think you didnt read my comment too...that you need to be more careful before you write anything... as part of this site you should be able to understand that. Please mark the section where I have ask him to change Nginx to Apache...I will be eagerly waiting here to know.

Comment: You are saying he should ask his hosting provider for a rewrite module for apache and that he should fix permissions for an .htaccess file which nginx does not even use..